# Python GLM converges but R GLM doesn't?

Tags: python, r, statistics

I am trying to train an (identity link Poisson) GLM model on some data.  I built what I believe to be equivalent models in R and Python.  In R, the GLM fails to converge.  In Python, the GLM does converge.  Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Starting from the observation (R code)

```
b <- c(1607.72888, 1457.32996, 2230.17041, 2371.61865, 2759.7373, 
2200.35571, 3700.06104, 75333.8906, 33347.0156, 24970.9219, 5840.49512, 
2465.53516, 1882.85522, 1027.7406, 796.484009, 863.635925, 926.715149, 
1315.60522, 7734.25879, 255625, 130990.281, 71047.9375, 23927.1992, 
15792.1631, 13041.4033, 6688.22559, 2822.23682, 2115.25049, 1618.78552, 
1517.86987, 482027.531, 213073.016, 98384.4844, 35729.2227, 21157.3594, 
16215.7432, 14006.8438, 4750.69092, 3116.08838, 1554.2738, 587.872559, 
0, 0, 64.625, 16.4270325, 37.5073662, 274.369263, 0)
```

and the predictor

```
M <- c(-7.9675869936053e-06, -2.9465510727696e-06, -2.21335646368051e-06, 
3.64491029094931e-05, 1.27785515404535e-05, 3.38522978187467e-05, 
0.00062461548108636, 0.0464058660868474, 0.0196678752619104, 
0.0153096807169331, 0.00349654677177638, 0.0015296157844073, 
0.00101697130553886, 0.00053606322761061, 0.00032545716927196, 
0.00015466321949303, 0.00037175222102242, 0.00032327446276574, 
0.00455841559776405, 0.169167191854014, 0.0871342536136015, 0.0473945835827427, 
0.0161442668339746, 0.010567700966009, 0.00948533330933113, 0.00421478996145066, 
0.00184265032175036, 0.00149379880911122, 0.00103486520709283, 
0.00093688509002056, 0.298346941396298, 0.133754666017589, 0.0633174899164175, 
0.0228254672410591, 0.0134052216553624, 0.0100745170940446, 0.00871104028108377, 
0.00284039230023698, 0.00189497902518704, 0.00080088467813307, 
1.5570018119882e-05, 5.27906279865597e-05, 5.36030668242488e-05, 
2.02817303022873e-05, 2.78819345726129e-05, 2.85829668669995e-05, 
1.83105158084491e-05, 4.3102208421767e-06)
```

or in python the observation

```
b = array([[1.60772888e+03],
       [1.45732996e+03],
       [2.23017041e+03],
       [2.37161865e+03],
       [2.75973730e+03],
       [2.20035571e+03],
       [3.70006104e+03],
       [7.53338906e+04],
       [3.33470156e+04],
       [2.49709219e+04],
       [5.84049512e+03],
       [2.46553516e+03],
       [1.88285522e+03],
       [1.02774060e+03],
       [7.96484009e+02],
       [8.63635925e+02],
       [9.26715149e+02],
       [1.31560522e+03],
       [7.73425879e+03],
       [2.55625000e+05],
       [1.30990281e+05],
       [7.10479375e+04],
       [2.39271992e+04],
       [1.57921631e+04],
       [1.30414033e+04],
       [6.68822559e+03],
       [2.82223682e+03],
       [2.11525049e+03],
       [1.61878552e+03],
       [1.51786987e+03],
       [4.82027531e+05],
       [2.13073016e+05],
       [9.83844844e+04],
       [3.57292227e+04],
       [2.11573594e+04],
       [1.62157432e+04],
       [1.40068438e+04],
       [4.75069092e+03],
       [3.11608838e+03],
       [1.55427380e+03],
       [5.87872559e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00],
       [6.46250000e+01],
       [1.64270325e+01],
       [3.75073662e+01],
       [2.74369263e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00]])
```

and the predictor

```
M = array([[-7.96758699e-06],
       [-2.94655107e-06],
       [-2.21335646e-06],
       [ 3.64491029e-05],
       [ 1.27785515e-05],
       [ 3.38522978e-05],
       [ 6.24615481e-04],
       [ 4.64058661e-02],
       [ 1.96678753e-02],
       [ 1.53096807e-02],
       [ 3.49654677e-03],
       [ 1.52961578e-03],
       [ 1.01697131e-03],
       [ 5.36063228e-04],
       [ 3.25457169e-04],
       [ 1.54663219e-04],
       [ 3.71752221e-04],
       [ 3.23274463e-04],
       [ 4.55841560e-03],
       [ 1.69167192e-01],
       [ 8.71342536e-02],
       [ 4.73945836e-02],
       [ 1.61442668e-02],
       [ 1.05677010e-02],
       [ 9.48533331e-03],
       [ 4.21478996e-03],
       [ 1.84265032e-03],
       [ 1.49379881e-03],
       [ 1.03486521e-03],
       [ 9.36885090e-04],
       [ 2.98346941e-01],
       [ 1.33754666e-01],
       [ 6.33174899e-02],
       [ 2.28254672e-02],
       [ 1.34052217e-02],
       [ 1.00745171e-02],
       [ 8.71104028e-03],
       [ 2.84039230e-03],
       [ 1.89497903e-03],
       [ 8.00884678e-04],
       [ 1.55700181e-05],
       [ 5.27906280e-05],
       [ 5.36030668e-05],
       [ 2.02817303e-05],
       [ 2.78819346e-05],
       [ 2.85829669e-05],
       [ 1.83105158e-05],
       [ 4.31022084e-06]])
```

I first tried to construct the glm using R's stats library with:

```
glm(b ~ 0 + M,
         family = poisson(identity)))
```

This fails to converge, with the error:

Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
In log(y/mu) : NaNs produced

I then built the following (I believe equivalent) python model:

```
poiReg = sm.GLM(b, M, family = 
       sm.families.Poisson(link = 
                           sm.families.links.identity())).fit()
```

and this model converged to 1578382.6635341388

Comment: Since you're having trouble with the R version, it would be nice to share the sample data in valid R syntax.

Comment: Your model is nonsense. The Poisson distribution is a discrete distribution (of counts, i.e., integer values). Your DV is not integer.

Comment: Also, when plotting the data, the basic property of the Poisson distribution (variance equals mean) is clearly not valid.

Comment: @Roland I found [this answer interesting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70065/7515) in presenting a use-case for a Poisson model with non-integer data, though that certainly doesn't seem to be the case for OP's data, and your point about the variance = mean assumption is a very good one.

Comment: @Roland It is noisy count data, and even for non-integral data this should be a meaningful model.  The noise is no different than the approximation discussed in Gregor's link.  Furthermore, rounding the data to integers as a pre-processing step does not cause the model to converge, so that this isn't the issue.

Comment: @Roland I understand that the data is overdispersed, so that a negative binomial model will ultimately be better.  I am interested in building a Poisson model to compare with it using some metrics like the chi-squared test.  Also, the negative binomial model will not converge in R either.

Comment: @GregorThomas your link is on point.  My data doesn't come from the same process, but I have theoretical reasons to believe it is the result of a count process plus noise.

Comment: @librus How can "noisy count data" be non-integer? That's not possible unless the data has been processed (e.g., averaged) after the count process and then it is not count data anymore.

Comment: Personally, I would model this with the normal distribution and account for the heteroskedasticity with robust standard errors or by including a variance structure in the model.

Comment: Identity link Poisson GLMs are badly supported in R, because the algo currently doesn't enforce nonnegativity constraints on the fitted coefficients, which is required for identity link Poisson to converge. Given that you data are not counts it seems your data do not conform to identity link Poisson though. Maybe a gls model with a particular mean-variance relationship specified via the weights argument would be better?